Old files on the /run tmpfs?
How I have a file in the directory /run/user/1003/doc/15336747/ from last month if /run is a tmpfs and the computer was turned off/on yesterday?
Moreover:
valentin@darkstar:/run/user/1003/doc$ df -h /run/user/1003/
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
tmpfs           1.6G  260K  1.6G   1% /run/user/1003
valentin@darkstar:/run/user/1003/doc$ df -h /run/user/1003/doc/
df: /run/user/1003/doc/: Operation not permitted
valentin@darkstar:/run/user/1003/doc$ sudo df -h /run/user/1003/doc/
df: /run/user/1003/doc/: Permission denied
valentin@darkstar:/run/user/1003/doc$ 

This is related to the Chromium web browser installed with snap. It looks like the browser if writing the files I upload and download in the /run tmpfs.
